# EzPublish different template based on page type

Tags: php, templates, symfony, twig, ezpublish

Is it possible in EzPublish 5 to use a different template based on the page type you are currently on?
I mean, I am 99,99% sure that this is possible, otherwise the CMS wouldn't be so useful ;) But the main question is: does anyone know how to do this?

If I go to mysite/products I would like to have the page_products.html.twig template, and if I go to mysite/retailers I would like to have the page_retailers.html.twig template, and so on, and so on.

Now this is probably fairly easy to achieve, but somehow I can't figure it out myself. Any clue anyone ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to read documentation about [template matching](https://confluence.ez.no/display/EZP/View+provider+configuration).

Simplest way is to make products and retailers `folder` and set different sections.

Comment: thanks! indeed what I was looking for, but didn't know how to search for it :)